# Smart Array P420i Permanently replace Predictive Failure Disk with Spare

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, hpe

I have a Smart Array P420i configured as below:

```
Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)
      logicaldrive 1 (838.1 GB, RAID 5, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, SAS HDD, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, SAS HDD, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:3 (port 1I:box 2:bay 3, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:4 (port 1I:box 2:bay 4, SAS HDD, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:5 (port 2I:box 2:bay 5, SAS HDD, 300 GB, OK, spare)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:6 (port 2I:box 2:bay 6, SAS HDD, 300 GB, OK, spare)
```

I don't have onsite access but would like to replace disk 3 with disk 6 permanently to prevent any issues occuring when Disk 3 eventually fails. Normally, i would just physically replace disk 6 with the disk in bay 3 but I do not have physical access to the server.
ie, I want to remove disk 3 from the array, and add disk 6 permanently leaving Disk 5 as a SPARE.
Is this possible with SSACLI (or HPSSACLI commands)?

The problem is if I remove Disk 3, Disk 5 will be made spare active. When I add Disk 6 to the logicaldrive, then wont it just extend the logical drive rather than make Disk 5 Spare again?